# How to store Enum into Cassandra with Springdata?

Tags: java, enums, cassandra, spring-data

I am trying to store an enum into Cassandra using the Springdata framework. Is this possible? I have defined my enum:

```
public enum Currency {
     GBP, 
     USD, 
     EUR
}
```

Then I define my class with the "@Enumerated" annotation on the field:

```
@Table
public class BondStatic {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    private String isin;
    private String ticker;
    private Date maturity;
    private Double coupon;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Currency currency;
    ...
}
```

These are my imports:

```
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.EnumType;
import com.datastax.driver.mapping.annotations.Enumerated;
```

Then I have my Component class for Spring:

```
@Component
class CassandraDataCLR implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    public BondStaticCassandraRepository bondStaticRepository;
    ...
}
```

Which is autowired from:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(path = "/bond-static")
interface BondStaticCassandraRepository extends CassandraRepository<BondStatic> { }
```

Where these are my imports:

```
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.CassandraRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;
```

But when I try to run the following:

```
bondStaticRepository.save(bondStatics);
```

I get:

> Value 0 of type class pojo.PocEnums$Currency does not correspond to
>   any CQL3 type

Any suggestions? The simple solution would be to make my fields into String and use the enum in the getter and setter, but it seems like having an annotated enum is a much cleaner solution if I can get it to work.

Comment: Hi @Matt, the current solution is to change the property to `String`. It's actually a bug inside of Spring Data Cassandra, I created  a bug report ticket [DATACASS-260](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-260). Spring Data Cassandra does not use the `cassandra-driver-mapping` module but has its own mapping layer so annotations from `cassandra-driver-mapping` are not read by Spring Data Cassandra.

Comment: Ah ok, that's what we ended up doing - glad to know it's not just me being dense! We tried both "@CassandraType" and "@Enumerated" and neither worked... If you make that an answer I'll accept it :)

Comment: `@CassandraType` is already part of Spring Data Cassandra so the bugfix would require `@CassandraType(type = Name.ASCII/VARCHAR/TEXT or INT)` on your property to convert it either to string or to a numeric (ordinal) value.